# How to send Query Params in Get Request in Robot Framework?

Tags: rest, automation, robotframework

I am new to Robot Framework and am facing an issue while sending query params in Get Request method.
Following is the code that I tried with no luck :

```
Get Data With Filter
    [Arguments]    ${type}    ${filter}
    ${auth} =    Create List    ${user_name}    ${password}
    ${params} =    Create Dictionary    type=${type}    filter=${filter}
    Create Session    testingapi    url=${some_host_name}    auth=${auth}
    ${resp} =    Get Request    testingapi   /foo/data    params=${params}
    Log  ${resp}
```

${type} has value **new** and ${filter} that I want is **id:"1234"**

I am expecting final url to formed as :
`/foo/data?type=new&filter=id%3A1234`

Instead of forming the expected url, I get the request url as :

`GET Request using : uri=/foo/data, params={'type': 'new', 'filter': 'id:1234'}`

I might be missing something very obvious but I cant figure out what it is. What can I change in this piece of code or any new code that needs to be added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the logger is just outputting the `params` as the dictionary. The request should actually be made to `foo/data?type=new&filter=id%3A1234`

You can test it with the following request to Postman Echo (An HTTP testing service):

```
    ${auth} =    Create List    Mark    SuperSecret
    ${params} =    Create Dictionary    type=Condos    filter=2Bedrooms
    Create Session    testingapi    url=http://postman-echo.com    auth=${auth}
    ${resp} =    Get Request    testingapi   /get    params=${params}

    ${json} =  To JSON  ${resp.content}  pretty_print=True
    Log  \n${json}  console=yes
```

The response will correctly list the params you've encoded:

```
{
    "args": {
        "filter": "2Bedrooms",
        "type": "Condos"
    },
    "headers": {
        "accept": "*/*",
        "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
        "authorization": "Basic TWFyazpTdXBlclNlY3JldA==",
        "host": "postman-echo.com",
        "user-agent": "python-requests/2.25.0",
        "x-amzn-trace-id": "Root=1-5fb43ae9-1880b0a621c864b06ce1f54a",
        "x-forwarded-port": "80",
        "x-forwarded-proto": "http"
    },
    "url": "http://postman-echo.com/get?type=Condos&filter=2Bedrooms"
}
```